# How to use StepArgumentTransformation properly in Specflow(BDD)?

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

I encountered a scenario where i have to send an array of integers as parameter from specflow feature file. I could have used tables which i don't want to do as i have send as row[] or col[]. If i pass parameter as a string

eg: Given set the value as '470,471,472,472'

and receive it and do split in step definition file. How different is StepArgumentTransformation from the above scenario? Is any other benefit in using step argument transformation. I understand we can convert  XML,Date or any object. Why do we have to use stepargumenttransformation???

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood the question correctly.

Specflow supports some automatic transformation out of the box, so things like converting to `Date`, `Double`, `int` etc etc, and it does these by default as there is no ambiguity about them. You can easily convert a string to a `double` or a `Date` as you know the locale being used.

Why isn't converting to arrays supported? I suppose it could be, but there is some ambiguity. What should the list separator be? a comma? What about locales that use that as a separator between the whole and fractional part of a number?

So providing a default implementation of something which converted a list to `int[]` or `IEnumerable<int>` could be possible, but its just likely to get some people asking why it doesn't work for them when they have used ☃ as a list separator.

It's better to leave the things with ambiguity to individuals to implement, rather than guess at the best implementation.

The StepArgumentTransformation you want is very simple to write and could be included in an external step assembly if you wanted to share it amongst many projects.

So to answer your many questions:

It's not really any different, it just encapsulates  it in a single place, which is good practise, which is a benefit.

Yes you can convert any object.

You don't have to use StepArgumentTransformation, many people don't, but IMHO they make your life much easier

Comment: I implemented without using StepArgumentTransformation, Specflow itself transforms string, integer parameter from feature file. I haven't tried StepArgumentTransformation in an external step assembly and normally either. I give a try and let you know.. Thanks for your explanation and valuable time. :)